# How to Set Multiple Cookies for Multiple Dynamic Divs

Tags: javascript, cookies, hidden-field, dynamic-content, custom-object

Would like help setting multiple cookies for multiple dynamic divs.

I am able to set 1 cookie for 1 div, but, when I add more than 1 item/div to the cart, the cookies are only getting set on the first child/div.

The number of divs being added to the cart will always be unknown and dynamically generated... how can I create unique cookies for each of the cart items being added?

Thank you so much for your time & help! any help would be greatly appreciated,
Steve.

**CODE AVAILABLE HERE**

```js
 $('#bag_active').on('click', '.add-to-cart', function setCookie() {  
    alert("COOKIES SET");

    var customObject = {};

    customObject.name = document.getElementById("cart_product_name").value;
    customObject.price = document.getElementById("cart_product_price").value;

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(customObject);

    document.cookie = "cookieObject=" + jsonString;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bag_active" class="product-card">
    <h1 class="title">Cookie Title 1</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">Cookie Price 1</h2>
    <button id="1" type="button" class="btn add-to-cart" aria-pressed="true" onclick="setCookie()">Add to Bag</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="cart_product_name" name="Cookie Name 1" value="Cookie Name 1">
    <input type="hidden" id="cart_product_price" name="Cookie Price 1" value="Cookie Price 1">
</div>

<div id="bag_active" class="product-card">
    <h1 class="title">Cookie Title 2</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">Cookie Price 2</h2>
    <button id="2" type="button" class="btn add-to-cart" aria-pressed="true" onclick="setCookie()">Add to Bag</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="cart_product_name" name="Cookie Name 2" value="Cookie Name 2">
    <input type="hidden" id="cart_product_price" name="Cookie Price 2" value="Cookie Price 2">
</div>

<div id="bag_active" class="product-card">
    <h1 class="title">Cookie Title 3</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">Cookie Price 3</h2>
    <button id="3" type="button" class="btn add-to-cart" aria-pressed="true" onclick="setCookie()">Add to Bag</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="cart_product_name" name="Cookie Name 3" value="Cookie Name 3">
    <input type="hidden" id="cart_product_price" name="Cookie Price 3" value="Cookie Price 3">
</div>
```

Comment: Read the previously set cookie, parse it, add new info, serialize and store it again.

Comment: @aleksxor Thank you so much, hate to be that guy lol but how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume you rewrite your click handler to something like:

```js
// some cookie helpers in vanilla-js. or you can use a library to work with cookies
function getCookie(name, text) {
  if (typeof text !== 'string') return null

  var nameEQ = `${name}=`
  var ca = text.split(/[;&]/)

  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i += 1) {
    var c = ca[i]
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1, c.length)
    }
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
      return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length)
    }
  }

  return null
}

function parseCookie(cookie) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(cookie)
  } catch (err) {
    return null
  }
}
// --- end cookie helpers ---

$('#bag_active').on('click', '#checkout_button', function setCookie() {
  var cookieObject = parseCookie(getCookie('cookieObject', document.cookie)) || { orders: [] }

  if (!Array.isArray(cookieObject.orders)) throw new Error('Malformed cookie!')

  var newOrder = {}
  newOrder.name = document.getElementById("cart_product_name").value
  newOrder.price = document.getElementById("cart_product_price").value
  cookieObject.orders.push(newOrder)

  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(cookieObject)

  document.cookie = "cookieObject=" + jsonString
})
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully for dynamic "add to cart" of course I needed to update the mental model / workflow so that cookie storing was occurring on "Add to Cart" instead of "Cart Submission" so great foresight on your part there. Thank you ❤️

Comment: I made another question here which revolves around "Removing/Deleting" cookies from the JSON string when the items they were set by get deleted... question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807134/how-to-delete-dynamic-cookies-from-json-strings - if you have the time :)